# jQuery UI Selectable in Overflowed Div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, selectable

We have a list of items and we need to allow the user to select more than one of them.  Instead of just using the default html select element with the multiselect attribute we would like to use the jQuery UI selectable interaction.  We have it all wired up and it works great except if the list of items is long, we put it inside a div that will overflow at a certain height.  The problem is that if the user clicks and drags to select multiple items in the list and they want to be able to select items that are not visible but in the overflowed portion of the div, if they drag their mouse down outside of the div, it doesn't automatically scroll to the "hidden" portions of the div like a normal multi-select element would.

I have no doubt we could handle the mousemove or mouseleave events of the div and scroll it manually but I was wondering if there was a way anyone was aware to do this automatically or what the simplest way to do it is.

Here is a jsfiddle showing what doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/CAZxk/

If you click on Item 1 and drag down, once you leave the demo div, I would like the ul to scroll so items 6, 7, etc start to show.

Comment: Not going completely off-topic, but the [Sortable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) does exactly that. Maybe someone can analyze its code and check if it does it in a simple way..

Answer (score 1):

This was fairly straightforward to convert from the code in the sortable plugin.  I just put this in the selectable 'start' function:

```
$(window).mousemove(function(e) {

    var sensitivity = 10, speed = 20, $d = $(document);

    if (e.pageY - $d.scrollTop() < sensitivity) {

        $d.scrollTop($d.scrollTop() - speed);    // scroll up

    } else if ($(window).height() - (e.pageY - $d.scrollTop()) < sensitivity) {

        $d.scrollTop($d.scrollTop() + speed);    // scroll down

    }

    if (e.pageX - $d.scrollLeft() < sensitivity) {

        $d.scrollLeft($d.scrollLeft() - speed);  // scroll left

    } else if ($(window).width() - (e.pageX - $d.scrollLeft()) < sensitivity) {

        $d.scrollLeft($d.scrollLeft() + speed);  // scroll right

    }

});
```

And turned off the listener in the selectable 'stop' function:

```
$(window).unbind('mousemove');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the jQuery UI Selectable plugin -

> http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3223.

jQuery UI Sortable does provide this functionality so you might be look at what was done there to help.  The jQuery UI ticket has a link containing the source code used to implement this in Sortable.